# How to add Other Application in Project?

Tags: delphi

How to add Other Application in Project?

Comment: specify the version of Delphi you are referring to.

Comment: Please ddd more details of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You don't add applications you add Projects to the current project group. You can right click on the project group and select "Add Existing Project" or "Add New Project". However, this is Delphi 2009, not sure about other versions.

Comment: It's the same in all Delphi versions that support project groups, which I think began at version 4.

Comment: Ah cool, wasn't sure hadn't used anything prior to Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 2):

Normally one adds a project to a project group, but your question is too vague to determine if this is what you're trying to do.